# caliburn.micro not showing dialog after application install

Tags: wpf, setup-project, caliburn.micro

i've got a bit of a problem with caliburn micro 1.4.0 and wpf.
So here's the rundown of the problem. I've created a visual studio installer project. Added the project output from my app. so far so good.
The application installs without a problem. i can run the application without problems, but when i try to close the application a popup dialog should appear. but nothing happens, no dialog, just a black window nothing more.

here's the code from my shellviewmodel to show the dialog:

```
public override void CanClose(Action<bool> callback)
        {
            var modalD = IoC.Get<ModalDialogViewModel>();
            modalD.TituloModal = "Encerrar Aplicação";
            modalD.MensagemModal = "Deseja encerrar a aplicação?";
            modalD.ModalHeight = 250;
            modalD.ModalWidth = 250;
            bool? result = WindowManagerWindow.ShowDialog(modalD);
            if (result == null) return;
            if ((bool) result)
            {
                callback(true);
            }
            else
            {
                callback(false);
            }
        }
```

any ideas on how to solve this issue?
help would be appreciated
thanks in advance

Comment: Can you test the program from Visual Studio?  Do you see any errors in the Output window?

Comment: looks ok in the output at least at first sight  my output looks somewhat like this [link] (http://pastebin.com/AdRXGa6x)

Answer (score 0):

I have responded on the Caliburn.Micro discussion you created. I don't think this is a Caliburn.Micro problem, rather it sounds like you are missing DLL's.

I would first confirm there are no warnings on build and after that ensure the installation has all the DLL's that are in the debug bin.

Comment: running the application on release mode looks ok, no errors at first sight

Comment: it doesn't look like there's problems with the build. ran the app in release mode and the dll's are in the folder, caliburn.micro.dll and System.Windows.Interactivity are present. in a couple of hours i'm going to take another swing at it and re create the setup project and see if it's all copied and report back

Comment: Let me know how you get on, cheers!

Comment: ok.i've recreated the setup project, did a install test and i've compared both the folders. the debug/release build folder and the instalation folder both have the same dll files. i've just ran with the same problem. black screen on my app no dialogs whatsoever and cannot close it.

Comment: one thing that keeps bugging me. do i need to register caliburn.micro.dll and System.Windows.Interactivity.dll in the system? and do i need the xml files that accompany both of them?

Comment: @jonniebigodes I am going to have a quick ask around to see if any of the other devs have seen this, I have never come across this problem and due to its nature its hard to debug without having the source. Let me ask the question and get back to you.

Answer (score 0):

No registration of those dll's are required.  As for the this issue I see in the output that you are using EntLib and ServiceLocation and Unity, are you using these in the app for registration of the views and viewmodels secondly are you using them to instantiate the Dialog in question?

I would lean towards McDonnellDean's statement about it not being CM.  Appears you have a lot more going on than just a black messagebox.

Answer (score 0):

my problem was that i was forgetting some content files that needed to be added.
sorry, my bad. 
but thanks alot for the help given